# many to many table - 1 seperate field primary key or 2 existed fileds primary key (Example inside)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-structures

I have 2 tables with many to many relation:

```
student 
(
id int(11) NOT NULL, 
name varchar(255), 
primary key(id)
);

teacher
(
id int(11) NOT NULL, 
name varchar(255), 
primary key(id)
);
```

and I should do 3 table - student_has_teacher

1. **option add id separate field primary key**

   student_has_teacher
   (
   id int(11) NOT NULL,
   teacher_id int(11),
   student_id int(11)
   primary key(id)
   );
2. **option make 2 fields primary key**

   student_has_teacher
   (
   teacher_id int(11),
   student_id int(11),
   primary key(teacher_id,student_id),
   foreign key(teacher_id) references teacher(id),
   foreign key(student_id) references student(id)
   );

What is better option and why?

Thanks

Comment: id is the worst name for an id field. Please learn to use studentid, teacherid, etc. It makes a huge difference when you get to complex queries and reporting.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963809/should-i-use-composite-primary-keys-or-not, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159087/composite-primary-keys-versus-unique-object-id-field, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383062/composite-primary-key-to-use-or-not-to-use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two options are not equivalent. In option 1 there can be multiple pairings of each teacher and student. In option 2 only 1 row is permitted for each combination of teacher and student.

There is another difference as well. In 1 the student and teacher are nullable. In 2 they aren't.

On the information given I don't see why a teacher would need to be paired with the same student more than once. So as a guess I'd say that 2 was more appropriate, but it all depends on the business requirements and you haven't really given much information to say either way.

Answer (score 3):

> make 2 fields primary key

Because they fulfill the definition of what a primary key is. They allow to unambiguously indicate the row.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If you'll need to relate something to a row in `student_has_teacher` (weird table-name imo, I'd suggest `student_teacher`) an `id` field would be nice. If you're not, the two fields will do fine to.