# How to structure SQL data model to maintain data integrity

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema, data-modeling

### Background

I'm building a Private Chef booking service where you can book a Chef to cook you a custom Menu.  I'm having trouble creating a SQL db schema that accurately represents the domain while maintaining data integrity.

#### Requirements

- Customers create a `Booking` by selecting a `Chef` and a `Menu` and choose the `MenuItems` they want for each `MenuCourse`
- A `Chef` defines a set of `MenuItem` that a customer can choose from to create their `Booking`
- A `Menu` is a collection of `MenuCourses`. (ex. A `Menu` named "Tasting Menu" is a 6 course meal, where each `MenuCourse` costs between $10-20).
- A `Chef` should be able to associate their `MenuItems` with multiple `Menus` and `MenuCourses`.
- A customer `Booking` should contain the `Chef` the customer selected along with the `Menu` (and the `MenuItems`) that will be served. `Booking` price is determined by the `Menu` and `MenuCourse` selections (an appetizer costs less than an entree)

## Problem

In my current data model, I have the following issues that I'm not sure how to fix:

A. It's possible to create a `Booking` with `Chef` "A", but then have a `BookingMenuItem` that references a `MenuItem` with `Chef` "B" (all the `BookingMenuItem` for a `Booking` should belong to the same `Chef`)

B. A `Booking` references a particular `Menu` (which I need for pricing, pricing is based on `Menu` and `MenuCourse`) however a `BookingMenuItem` for that `Booking` could reference a completely different `Menu` or `MenuCourse`

Is it possible to re-design my db schema to fix the integrity problems I'm having? Or do I just have to implement these checks at the application level. Thanks!

[image: ERD]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem.

Comment: You are saying that once someone books cheesecake with Nigella Lawson, no one can ever book cheescake with anyone other chef?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid no, each chef defines their own set of menu items, and customer can book whatever they want based on which chef they pick as part of their booking....a chef can be booked multiple times by different customers

Comment: With regards to issue A, it seems like you should remove `chef_id` from `MenuItem`. You can work out what menuitems a particular chef is booked for and vice versa by traversing  the joins through to `Booking` With regards to issue B, is this because patrons might book a set menu or they might book a custom menu from individual items?

Answer (score 2):

This uses table names from your model and follows it as close as I could get it. I renamed `menu_item` to `dish`, to avoid confusion.

---

```
customer {CST}
     KEY {CST}
```

```
chef {CHF}
 KEY {CHF}
```

```
dish {CHF, DSH_NO}
 KEY {CHF, DSH_NO}

FK {CHF} REFERENCES chef {CHF}
```

```
menu {CHF, MNU_NO}
 KEY {CHF, MNU_NO}

FK {CHF} REFERENCES chef {CHF}
```

```
menu_course {CHF, MNU_NO, CRS_NO}
        KEY {CHF, MNU_NO, CRS_NO}

  FK {CHF, MNU_NO} REFERENCES
menu {CHF, MNU_NO}
```

```
menu_course_item { CHF
                 , MNU_NO
                 , CRS_NO
                 , CRS_ITM_NO
                 , DSH_NO
                 }
KEY {CHF, MNU_NO, CRS_NO, CRS_ITM_NO}

        FK1 {CHF, MNU_NO, CRS_NO} REFERENCES
menu_course {CHF, MNU_NO, CRS_NO}

 FK2 {CHF, DSH_NO} REFERENCES
dish {CHF, DSH_NO}
```

```
booking { CST
        , BOOK_NO
        , CHF
        , MNU_NO
        }
    KEY {CST, BOOK_NO}
     SK {CST, BOOK_NO, CHF, MNU_NO}

FK1 {CST} REFERENCES customer {CST}

 FK2 {CHF, MNU_NO} REFERENCES
menu {CHF, MNU_NO}
```

```
booking_menu_item { CST
                  , BOOK_NO
                  , CHF
                  , MNU_NO
                  , CRS_NO
                  , CRS_ITM_NO
                  }

KEY {CST, BOOK_NO, CHF, MNU_NO, CRS_NO, CRS_ITM_NO}

    FK1 {CST, BOOK_NO, CHF, MNU_NO} REFERENCES
booking {CST, BOOK_NO, CHF, MNU_NO}

             FK2 {CHF, MNU_NO, CRS_NO, CRS_ITM_NO} REFERENCES
menu_course_item {CHF, MNU_NO, CRS_NO, CRS_ITM_NO}
```

---

I have used generic term `KEY` for `PK or AK`. If, for some reason, you need to use single-column technical keys (`xx_ID`), make sure you add them, as described in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588304/composite-primary-key-vs-additional-id-column/14591232#14591232); if not, all these `KEY` are `PK`.

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

KEY = PK or AK

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```