# Normalization of Database with Multiple Attributes/Repetitions

Tags: database, database-normalization

I'm very new to studying database systems and am a little stuck on how to properly normalize a database with several multivalued attributes. For example, given the following:

[image]

I understand that to normalize into the first form, I must change the structure so that each column only has one attribute. So, there shouldn't be multiple genre, time, or cast attributes in each row.

I noticed that given a Movie, I know the Genre and Cast... so Movie functionally determines Genre and Cast.

Movie -> Genre, Cast

I know there is a lot of redundancy here and I'm not quite sure how to change the database into 2NF or 3NF. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & you show no research. Fragments of unreferenced beliefs/rumours are not helpful to solving or asking. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a textbook/reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck/unsure. Quote definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs. Google with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

Comment: Are you normalizing that **value** or a **variable**? If a variable, what exactly does that value have to do with it? PS ["1NF" has many meanings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) So tell us your definition & also textbook name & edition. PS "Redundancy" means nothing in particular. If "I know there is a lot of redundancy"--why, and what do you mean, exactly? Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).  Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation.

Comment: Take a look at these examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002623/verifying-non-key-column-dependencies-and-transitive-dependencies/65009855#65009855

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262601/need-help-with-bcnf-decomposition-problem/262793#262793