# SQL schema doubts

Tags: mysql, database-design

I wonder if this UML is valid, the "user_building_divisions" seems weird to me.

A user can create a record of food wasted in a building and each building can have multiple divisions, so a user works in a building and is assigned to a division, for example technology.

But some users can work in different buildings. So if I don't have that table when I create the record, I don't have the information on which building and division I can add the record to because it will only be to one of the buildings and divisions that the user has access to.

[image: SQL UML]

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Building BLD exists.
--
building {BLD}
      PK {BLD}
```

```
-- Division DIV (of a building) exists.
--
division {DIV}
      PK {DIV}
```

```
-- Building BLD has division DIV.
--
building_division {BLD, DIV}
               PK {BLD, DIV}

FK1 {BLD} REFERENCES building {BLD}
FK2 {DIV} REFERENCES division {DIV}
```

```
-- User USR exists.
--
user {USR}
  PK {USR}
```

```
-- User USR is assigned to building BLD,
-- division DIV.
--
user_building {USR, BLD, DIV}
           PK {USR, BLD, DIV}

FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user {USR}

              FK2 {BLD, DIV} REFERENCES 
building_division {BLD, DIV}
```

```
-- At (date-time) DTE, user USR created
-- a food-wasting record 
-- for building BLD, division DIV.
--
record_waste {USR, DTE, BLD, DIV}
          PK {USR, DTE}

          FK1 {USR, BLD, DIV} REFERENCES
user_building {USR, BLD, DIV}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

---

If you need, or prefer, single-column `PKs` *ADD* them as [described in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588304/composite-primary-key-vs-additional-id-column/14591232#14591232).

Comment: Nice to see we are suggesting the same data model. You build this on composite keys, while mine doesn't. For this small model this doesn't make much of a difference, but in general I consider a model based on composite keys superior. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two things here. There is an m:n relation between `user` and `building_divisions`. In an RDBMS you would model this with a bridge table (your `user_building_divisions` table). So either exclude this table from your UML and connect `user` and `building_divisions` with an m:n line or keep this table in your UML and link it with 1:n lines two its two parent tables.

There are more mistakes with m:n in your UML. A `division` has multiple `building_division`. But a building division belongs to only one division. That is 1:n. Same for `building` and `building_division`.

As to your overall data model:

- Do you find it necessary to split the user data into two 1:1 related tables? I find it just makes the model unnecessarily complicated.
- I think that you could model the tables in one line more or less: building and division make building divisions. A user links to building divisions. A user creates records on their linked building divisions.

This is how I'd model this:

```
user: user_id, email, country ...
  (unique constraint on email I guess)

building: building_id, name
  (unique constraint on name)

division: division_id, name
  (unique constraint on name)

building_division: building_division_id, building_id, division_id
  (unique constraint on building_id + division_id)

user_building_division: user_building_division_id, user_no, building_division_id
  (unique constraint on user_no + building_division_id)

user_building_division_record: user_building_division_record_id, user_building_division_id, ...
```

Comment: I understand everything except this "So either exclude this table from your UML and connect user and building_divisions with an m:n line "
If I do this m:n line, I need always an extra table "user_building_divisions" to handle it right?

Comment: Okay, I admit that was not clear. In a database you need a bridge table (also called junction table sometimes) to establish an m:n relation. In UML it suffices to draw a line and label the ends with m and n. But you can refine your UML to the point where you dissolve all m:n lines and show the bridge tables instead. Your bridge table `user_building_divisions` replaces/refines the m:n line you would otherwise have between `user` and `building_divisions`. It is 1:n related to the two tables, because one `user` can have many `user_building_divisions`, but one `user_building_divisions` belongs ...

Comment: ... to one `user`. Same for `user_building_divisions` and `building_divisions`: one `building_divisions` row can have many `user_building_divisions` rows, but one `user_building_divisions` row belongs to exactly one `building_divisions` row. So by showing the bridge tables in the UML you get rid of all m:n lines. Just decide how deep you model your UML. Either you show the real entities linked by 1:n and m:n or include the bridge tables thus losing all m:n lines. Or draw both, so as to have two models, one showing the business relations, one showing the database.