# Ensuring data consistency accross multiple tables in a postgresql Database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

The problem is the following:

I have 3 tables: Companies, Bundles, Documents, with foreign key relationships described in the folling diagrams.

[image: Database layout]

I don’t want two documents belonging to the same company to have the same reference.
I envision two solutions:

- Use a matrialized view with the company_id column of bundles and the reference column of document to create a unique index.
- Replicate the company_id column in the documents table, the downside being that i open a way for data inconsistency

Is there any cannonical solution for this problem ?

Comment: Is the relationship between Document and Bundle fixed? That is, once a Document is assigned to a Bundle it can never be re-assigned to a different Bundle? Is it ever possible to have a Document which doesn't belong to a Bundle (I guess not but worth asking)?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed, and every document belongs to a bundle

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to add a (redundant) unique constraint to `bundles (company_id, id)`, add `company_id` to `documents` as well and define the foreign key between `documents` and `bundles` on those two columns.

Then a simple unique constraint on `documents(reference, company_id)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Company COM exists.
--
company {COM}
     PK {COM}
```

```
-- Bundle number BU# of company COM exists .
--
bundle {COM, BU#}
    PK {COM, BU#}

FK {COM} REFERENCES company {COM}

-- For each company, bundle numbers are {1,2,3..}
```

```
-- Document number DO# of company COM is part of 
-- bundle number BU#, of that company.
--
document {COM, DO#, BU#}
      PK {COM, DO#}

FK {COM, BU#} REFERENCES bundle {COM, BU#} 

-- For each company, document numbers are {1,2,3..}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

```
Using suffix # to save on screen space.
OK for SQL Server and Oracle, for others use _NO.
For example, rename DO# to DO_NO.
```

If you need, or prefer, single-column `PKs`, you can *ADD* them as [described in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588304/composite-primary-key-vs-additional-id-column/14591232#14591232).