# Composite primary key or primary surrogate key with following scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know it's been asked many times, but I wanted to explain my scenario, and see if there are any benefits of using Identity column as primary key instead of using a composite primary key.

I'm currently reading two text files: File1 has Make & Model of car, while File2 has Make, Model, Year of car. Make, Model combination in File2 will always be in File1.

So I created table [Car] composed of columns of MakeId (identity), `Make` and `Model`. Data for table [Car] looks like this. The data in [Car] is an exact replica of File1:

```
[MakeId]       [Make]      [Model]
1              HONDA       ACCORD
2              HONDA       CIVIC
3              FORD        FOCUS
4              FORD        ESCORT
```

For File2, I created table [CarYear] with columns `CarYearId` (identity), `Make`, `Model`, `Year`. The data in [CarYear] is an exact replica of File2:

```
[CarYearId] [Make]      [Model]     [Year]
1           HONDA       ACCORD      2002
2           HONDA       ACCORD      2001
3           HONDA       ACCORD      2004
4           HONDA       CIVIC       1998
5           FORD        FOCUS       1998
6           FORD        ESCORT      2001
7           FORD        ESCORT      2002
```

Is there any reason why I shouldn't use Make, Model a composite primary key? Given my case, since I have Make & Model in both tables, I can easily just search the 2nd table directly instead of having to do inner joins.

Comment: This has been asked a lot (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383062/composite-primary-key and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337503/whats-the-best-practice-for-primary-keys-in-tables).  Honestly, I'd recommend doing it how it works best for your situation.  You should perhaps consider normalizing the data -- makes and models could be in their own table with a relationship table if needed.

Comment: it depends. lets assume, your make/model combination will never get any attributes since cars tend to need a year to identify the model. in that case i wont introduce a generated MakeId. Otherwise i Would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> File1 has Make & Model of car . . .

So the data of interest looks like this.

```
make        model
--
HONDA       ACCORD
HONDA       CIVIC
FORD        FOCUS
FORD        ESCORT
```

The column "make" is clearly not a candidate key. As far as you can tell from this sample of data, "model" *looks* like a candidate key. I actually had to research this issue several years ago, and I found only a couple of models that were built by more than one manufacturer, and none of those were current. But that doesn't really matter.

Whether the candidate key here is {make, model} or {model}, this table is in 6NF.<sup>1</sup> If we assume that the only candidate key is {make, model}, I might implement it like this in standard SQL.

```
create table car_models (
  make varchar(15) not null,
  model varchar(15) not null,
  primary key (make, model)
);
```

> File2 has Make, Model, Year of car.

So the data of interest looks like this.

```
make        model       year
--
HONDA       ACCORD      2002
HONDA       ACCORD      2001
HONDA       ACCORD      2004
HONDA       CIVIC       1998
FORD        FOCUS       1998
FORD        ESCORT      2001
FORD        ESCORT      2002
```

Following the assumptions about the key in the previous table, this table has only one candidate key, and it has only one additional attribute. It, too, is in 6NF. A SQL version might look like this.

```
create table car_model_years (
  make varchar(15) not null,
  model varchar(15) not null,
  model_year integer not null
    check (model_year between 1886 and 2099),
  primary key (make, model, model_year),
  foreign key (make, model) references car_models (make, model)
);
```

These tables have *no* redundant data. You can't remove any columns without breaking the semantics or compromising the integrity of the data. Foreign keys are repeated down the rows of "car_model_years", but that's not redundant--that's *exactly* what foreign keys are *for*.

> Is there any reason why I shouldn't use Make, Model a composite primary key?

As a theoretical (relational) matter, no, there isn't. If you start in 6NF, adding a surrogate ID number *denormalizes* that table. (6NF requires a *single* candidate key.) Even if you *do* add a surrogate ID number, you *still* have to declare {make, model} as `not null unique`. Failure to declare that constraint makes a table liable to end up looking like this.

```
model_id  make   model
--
1         Honda  Accord
2         Honda  Accord
3         Honda  Accord
```

As a practical matter, not a theoretical (relational) matter, these 6NF tables will probably perform better than denormalizations of them using surrogate ID numbers. For example, queries on "car_model_years" that are based on make and model will generally use an index-only scan--they won't have to read the base table at all.

As another practical matter, some application frameworks deal poorly with any key besides an id number. IMHO, this justifies using a better framework, though, not compromising the structure of your database.

---

1. "... a 'regular' relvar is in 6NF if and only if it consists of a single key, plus at most one additional attribute." Date, CJ, *Database in Depth: Relational Theory for Practitioners*, p 147. A regular relvar is a nontemporal relvar.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The two reasons for not wanting to use a surrogate key were: 1) I would need to search the primary table for every insert to retrieve the PK ID, 2) I tend to do many ad-hoc queries, so removing the unnecessary joins makes my job easier. I understand there's redundant data, but the pros outweigh the cons.

Comment: @rbhatup: There's no redundant data there. Search this page for "no redundant data".